# Need help with my SharePoint list validation formula. I cant seem to figure out how to combine the below statements. Any help is appreciated!

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, list, calculated-column-formula, list-validation

I have a SharePoint list with the fields listed in bold at the bottom.

I currently am using the below formula to validate that when options 1 and 3 are selected, I am requiring ticket number is not blank before the item can be added to the list.

```
=IF(OR([Task Type]="Option 1",[Task Type]="Option 3"),IF([Ticket Number]="",FALSE,TRUE),TRUE)
```

Id like to add to this validation, the ability to force the start dates to be today or in the future, not in the past.

How would I combine my validation formulas?  I have successfully got the below formula to work on its own for the start date, but can't seem to merge the 2 formulas so both are used for validation.

```
=[Planned Task Start Date]>=TODAY()
```

**Task Type** (Radio button selection)

Option 1

Option 2

Option 3

**Ticket Number** (Single line of text field)

**Start Date** (Date Field)

**End Date** (Date Field)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using below formula for your requirements:

```
=And(IF(OR([Task Type]="Option 1",[Task Type]="Option 3"),IF([Ticket Number]="",FALSE,TRUE),TRUE), [Planned Task Start Date]>=TODAY())
```

**Official Documentation**:

1. [Examples of common formulas in lists](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/examples-of-common-formulas-in-lists-d81f5f21-2b4e-45ce-b170-bf7ebf6988b3).

Comment: Dang you are a genius! One follow up question, how would the validation formula change if I added validation on the End Date field as well?  So I would verify the Ticket Number for being blank for options 1 and 3, and I would verify that the Start and the End Date fields had the current date or future dates entered?

Comment: Try this: `=And(IF(OR([Task Type]="Option 1",[Task Type]="Option 3"),IF([Ticket Number]="",FALSE,TRUE),TRUE), [Planned Task Start Date]>=TODAY(), [End Date]>=TODAY()`

Comment: You are awesome! thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily.